# Difference between retrieving a simple data and a file from ParseUser object

Tags: android, parse-platform, request

I realized while checking on Parse Analytics just now that request performance of my application is highly different than my predictions. Thus, I want to be clear about some issues. At first, I am curious about whether getting a large query is a good practice or not. In my situation, traversing all usernames is necessary. However, I could get 1000 users in a time and if my application will be used by 10000 people, I need to perform 10 consecutive queries.

Secondly, if I should get 5 different users by their usernames, I need to query 5 times. As result, I get 5 user objects and put these into an array to use later. If I need to get the value of Location GeoPoint of these user objects, does this operation count as a new request? Instead of getting location, if I need to get profile images of these users from corresponding objects, how many requests are done while streaming the image file (let's say the file is retrieved in 5 seconds)?

Thirdly, what is the best method to get some user objects by username? Querying "# of users" times as I said or is there a better way?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Less queries is better for cost savings. But each query will take longer (obviously).
2. You can use .include() to include any pointers inside that object. So if you are storing location as a pointer then make sure you include so that you can grab it all in one query (again, cost savings). If you are not, then it's definitely just one query (basically its automatically included as part of your query return). For images you get a url back, so IIRC, loading the image from that url doesn't count as a query.
3. You can stack multiple queries into one if you want. Check out  ParseQuery.or().

Something to note: Parse only allows a skip of 10,000. So if you want to get more than 10,000 users, you cannot use .skip(), instead you need to use something else like createAt. So you can do, get 1000 users .whereGreaterThan(date) or whereLessThan(date).

Comment: 2. I mentioned about getting location value of a user that is already queried. If there is a user object as the result of query and I call its location value, does it count as an additional request or the only request here is querying for this specific user?
3. I know .or() but does not it cost too many query? To me, it equals "# of users" times query for selecting indicated users and +1 for or query. Instead of this, may I put these usernames into an array and perform query.whereContainedIn(array)?

Comment: 2. I believe the only query is querying the specific user. 
3.You have to test it out, but AFAIK you can't put the usernames into an array and query.

Comment: 3. Since usernames are phone numbers of users in my application, when a user selects numbers from his contacts, he actually selects potential usernames. Thence, the selected values can be put into array and be queried with .whereContainedIn(). Thank you for your answer by the way.